# No Wifi connection with Acer Aspire 5741G

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my Acer Aspire 5741G  (8GB RAM, Window 7). After installing Ubuntu, I could not connect to Wifi. Although I dragged down the Wifi option, enabled the connection, but I get no connection. I even tried installing a fresh copy, but the problem remains the same. Help.

Comment: Do you have Wifi enabled in the Bios? On some computers turning off Wifi in Windows will turn it off in the Bios and make it impossible to turn on in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can we at least know what is the model of your wireless card?

Answer (score 2):

First check your wifi is hardblocked or softblocked by running the below command,

```
sudo rfkill list
```

If your wifi is softblocked then run the below command to unblock,

```
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```

If your wifi is hardblocked then you have to turn on the wifi hardware switch.