# Why if my system is 64-bit, I can't install Ubuntu 64-bit in virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit

I'm on windows 7 64 bit, Intel Core i7 3612QM, NVIDIA GeForce GT640M 2GB, 8GB RAM, 240GB SSD and 500GB HDD.

I want to delete and get rid of windows 7 partition and install Ubuntu 13.10 on my 240GB SSD.

I tried installing Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit on virtualbox but I get this error:

> **This Kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.**

I have checked my CPU details here:
[Intel Core i7 3612QM](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i7-3612QM-Notebook-Processor.73465.0.html)

If you scroll a bit to that site, you can see there: **64 Bit - 64 Bit support**

I want to install Ubuntu 64 bit, but is my computer compatible with it?

Comment: Boot the install cd and find out...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however i don't have an installation CD. Is it possible if i use a USB instead?

Comment: Yes boot from either DVD or USB and try without installing. Check everything works. If it does install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your computer is compatible to install 64 bit version of Ubuntu.Your virtualbox software may be 32 bit,so that it displays error like that.

If you still had doubt on whether your system supports Ubuntu 64 bit or not,you may bootup the Ubuntu installation disk and click on **Try Ubuntu** option.There you can test the full features of Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 or he may have a 64bit VB but did not make sure that he set up a 64bit virtual system, it will select 32 bit by default, you have to scroll down one to get to 64bit, that caught me the first time I used VB....

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answers @Avinash Raj and TrailRider. 

However. Download section of Virtualbox says VirtualBox 4.3.4 for Windows hosts  x86/amd64. That means that on a single installer both 32 and 64 is supported right? 

Also, how do you set up a 64bit virtual system? I don't get where should i scroll down?

Thanks for the helpful answers.

Cheers!

Comment: yes,it is possible to create bootable usb.Try to create bootable ubuntu usb through unetbootin software.

Comment: I'll be following this guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: ok,let's try that.

Comment: I'll be trying it now, be right back in a couple of minutes :) Wish me luck!

Comment: Hi Avinash, it went successful. I was able to try it on 64 bit. But i couldn't connect to my wifi, so i went back here to let you know how it goes.

From my quick experience running it. I can say that it was speedy, so fast that i didn't want to go back to windows again. But there's no wifi, so i'm in windows now. Is there anything i need to know why i couldn't connect to my wifi?

Comment: click on the network icon on the top panel and then select enable wifi.

Comment: It is already enabled. Also, the button is disabled, you can't click on it

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/384042/no-wifi-connection/384043#384043

Comment: Thanks again Avinash, i guess i'll have to dual boot first. But i'll try what you suggested. Thanks a lot :)